# Swagger with spring boot works when built on some machines, but not others

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jenkins, swagger-ui

When I build the spring boot application with swagger on my machine (Linux, Ubuntu 14, Oracle JDK1.8, Maven 3.5.2) it runs with swagger documentation fine.

If build on a windows machine the swagger-ui also works fine.

When I build the spring boot application with swagger on our Jenkins Build machine. (Linux, Ubuntu 16, Oracle JDK1.8, Maven 3.5.2) the application runs OK, but the swagger gives a 404 at the swagger-ui,html page:

```
14:01:28.296 [http-nio-30020-exec-1] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/v2/swagger-ui.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

This happens both via jenkins, and via a `mvn clean install` ran on the commandline.

I can't think of any reason that the Jenkins machine would be building it differently, but it appears to be! Is there something obvious I've missed? I see other people having the issue of if the documentation appears at all or not, but I haven't seen it working when build on select machines.

[Edit] Further testing reveals that a fresh install on an Ubuntu 14 (32bit or 64 bit) works fine, while a fresh install of java/maven on a different Ubuntu16 64bit machine doesn't work.

It also works on a fresh Ubuntu17 install, but does not work on a fresh Ubuntu16 install, with identical maven.tar.gz and jdk.tar.gz installations scped up.

It seems the jar files produced are identical if you unzip and diff the contents. But, if you re-zip up the non-functional file into a new jar, you can get one that works.

The only difference between the jar files is the ordering of the files returned if you run `unzip -l .jar`.

So it seems that the order the files are added to the jar is critical.

Comment: there could be plenty of reasons why jenkins box is building things differently, i.e. different environment variables, different maven settings, different maven profiles. If possible, get `mvn help:effective-pom` from jenkins box and compare it with one from your machine. The same could be done with adding `-X` to your maven command line and comparing (using some diff tool) output captured in both environments.

Comment: your accessing via: http://<host>:<port>/<app context>/swagger-ui.html  ??

Comment: @diginoise effective poms are identical (other than timestamps) I'm looking into the -X now.

Comment: @diginoise Maven -X shows no differences other than the linux kernel versions, but the order of adding files to the jar, creating .class files and running the junit tests is very different. Perhaps its an ordering issue with overwriting something in the jar?

Comment: junit, should be mixing the order up anyway (or so I think) just to make sure there are no inter-test dependencies. How does Jenkins run the application at all? `mvn spring-boot:run`? if jenkins does not run it, how do you run that build to test it? do you download jar/war and just run it?

Comment: It's scping it to the host machine and running with java -jar <jarfile>. In my recent testing I've found that a fresh Ubuntu16 will not work, and a fresh Ubuntu17 with identical java and maven binaries will work, just runing mvn clean install, then java -jar target/jar.jar.

Comment: @diginoise Unziping and re-ziping the .jar file makes it work. The only thing that’s different between the jar files is the order of files shown using unzip -l file.jar. It seems that order is important!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Is it needed to change order in pom?

Comment: @JakubWisniewski I have still not solved this :(

Comment: Hi, @Nick I met same problem recently. My jar built from linux does not work well but work well when being built from windows. After re-ziping jar built from linux, it's ok. My re-ziping is that I move some class outside then move back. I want to know if you solve it at last.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have both dependecies below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${springfox.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I have no problem building my swagger apps with jenkins or with mvn clean package

Comment: Yup, that's in the POM. It builds fine on a fresh Ubuntu14 machine, just when build on a Ubuntu16 machine I get the 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue when built app under my user account and started it under root (sudo). `sudo mvn spring-boot:run` solved the issue.